# LVM Write Stalls When Cache Fills

Tags: centos, lvm, storage

I'm currently encountering a very perplexing issue with my media server. I have an LV set up with a few disks, and that LV has a write cache attached to it. When the cache isn't full, it works wonderfully, but the moment it fills, any uploads to the server immediately stall out. The cache is 50GB, so currently I'm unable to upload anything bigger than 50GB, which is getting quite frustrating.

The LVM is 5 2TB drives, with a 50GB SSD as a write cache.

I can't imagine this is standard behavior, so I'm wondering what in the world is going on with my cache/LV setup. Is there anything that could cause this issue?

Comment: How was that LV created?

Comment: @Nils I'm afraid I'm not entirely certain what you mean. It should just be the "default" way of adding a writecache to an LV, if there is such a thing. As for the rest of it, I didn't even know there were multiple ways of doing it. IIRC, it's all default options, etc. There's nothing special to it.

Comment: According to the [man Page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html)  you can set blocksize and high water mark... Die you create a Filesystem in the LVs before caching IT? Please detail your steps.